# MySQL query to return a daily 30-day count

Tags: mysql

Let's say that one has a pair of tables:

**users**

| user_id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | email1@test.com |
| 2 | email2@test.com |
| ... | ... |

**logins**

| login_id | user_id | date_login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2038-01-19 03:14:07 |
| 2 | 1 | 2038-01-19 03:14:08 |
| 3 | 2 | 2038-01-19 03:14:08 |
| ... | ... | ... |

and one wanted to get a list of totals of "active users" for each day of the last year; ***where "active user" is defined as anyone who had logged in within 30 days of each date in question***.

e.g. result:

| date_count | activeuser_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2038-01-19 | 2345 |
| 2038-01-20 | 3456 |
| 2038-01-21 | 4321 |
| ... | ... |

How would one do this most efficiently / with the fewest number of queries?

Answer (score 0):

select * from users inner join logins on users.user_id = logins.user_id where date_diff(now(), date_login) <= 30

Comment: Sorry: was looking for the total number of active users for each day, not a list of the active users for each day